# What to return when failing to update a resource via API request? The resource or an error?

Tags: http-status-codes

Suppose I'm trying to update a user via an API request to change his status to "active":

```
PUT http://example.com/user/12/activate
```

What should my request handler return if the user is already "active"? Should I return a 200 response with the unmodified user object as its content, or should I return a 500 response with an error description?

If I should return the user object, how can the client know that something went wrong? Should I use a status code other than 200?

Answer (score 0):

You can return 409 Conflict HTTP status code in such cases.

You can learn about various HTTP status code using the links below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409